# Regular expression for detecting !this not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to implement support for a new language in VS Code, using a `tmGrammar` json file. In this language variables start with `!`, and there is a special reserved variable called `!this` in this language.

I want to apply one class to all common variables and other for the `!this` variable. I'm doing this in my json file:

```
"repository": {
    "keywords": {
        "patterns": [
            {
                "name": "constant.character",
                "match": "(?i)\\b(!this)\\b"
            },
            {
                "name": "variable.other",
                "match": "(?i)\\![a-z0-9]+"
            },
     }
  }
```

But this is coloring both `!this` and `!someVar` to the same color.

If I change the first rule to `(?i)\\b(this)\\b`, without the `!` the word `this` get colored correctly.

I also tried do change the order of the rules, but now matter what I do makes `!this` the same color as common variables.

Is there a problem with the first regular expression?

Comment: I already tried, it didn't work.

Comment: How about using this in your `variable.other` scope: `(?i)![a-z0-9]+\\b(?<!!this)` ?  Does the `!` need to be escaped in this case?

Comment: Nice! Didn't solve the problem but now we know there's a problem with the first expression. With your suggestion the common variable names are still colored, but the `!this` variable is not getting any color class at all. Looks like the `!` has a special function in the regex language used in the grammar file

Comment: @Mark Solved changing it to `(?i)!this`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you escaped the `!` in the second regex, why not in the first if the meaning is special in the grammar files. If so it should be in the documentation.